# How to rearrange a list based on the position of a sorted list?

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists of the same size:

```
List<string> ID_x = new List<string>()
{
    "ID2", "ID3", "ID2", "ID1", "ID4", "ID1",
};

List<double> D_x = new List<double>()
{
    3.5, 8.8, 1.1, 2.3, 3.5, 6.8,
};
```

I want to sort the list D_x from largest to smallest value but at the same time change the list ID_x such that if the element 8.8 in the list D_x (which is at the position 1) is changed to the position 0 (because is the largest value) then the element of list ID_x at the position 1 is also changed to the position 0, and so on, the new two lists should contain something like:

```
new D_x list {8.8 , 6.8 , 3.5 , 3.5 , 2.3 , 1.1}
new ID_x list {ID3 , ID1 , ID2 , ID4 , ID1 , ID2}
```

Comment: Can you please provide real data as valid C# code and also what the actual output looks like? Right we don't have enough detail without making up our own data, and, quite frankly, I'm struggling to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for your reply, i have edited my post so maybe my question is more clear now, thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you need:

```
List<string> ID_x = new List<string>()
{
    "ID2", "ID3", "ID2", "ID1", "ID4", "ID1",
};

List<double> D_x = new List<double>()
{
    3.5, 8.8, 1.1, 2.3, 3.5, 6.8,
};

var output =
    ID_x
        .Zip(D_x, (i, d) => new { i, d })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.d)
        .ToArray();

ID_x = output.Select(x => x.i).ToList();

D_x = output.Select(x => x.d).ToList();
```

The `Zip` operator is crucial here. It zips together the two equal sized lists.